# Describe the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ as a ring with finitely many multiplicative generators.

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is problem 13 on page 259 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology text:

> Describe $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ as a ring with finitely many multiplicative generators.

Here's my attempt to solve the problem. Since the CW structure of $\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1$ is given by the cells of $\mathbb{CP}^\infty -\mathbb{CP}^1$ plus an extra $0$-cell, the  cellular cochain complex of $\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1$ is of the form $$\cdots  \xleftarrow{} \mathbb{Z} \xleftarrow{}0 \xleftarrow{} \mathbb{Z} \xleftarrow{} 0 \xleftarrow{} \mathbb{Z} \xleftarrow{} 0 \xleftarrow{} 0\xleftarrow{} 0 \xleftarrow{} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$$ and is the same as $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ after degree $2$ so we have that $H^i(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1) = H^i(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)$ for $i > 2$, $H^1(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1) = 0$ and $H^0(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1) = \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. This describes $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ additively.

Now if I let $\alpha, \beta$ be the two generators of $H^0(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1)$ then one sees that $\alpha^2 = \beta^2 = 0$, we also get that since $\alpha, \beta$ lie in degree $0$, by graded commutativity of the cup product we get that $\alpha \cup \beta = (-1)^{0 \cdot 0}\beta \cup \alpha = \beta \cup \alpha$.

Now remember that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ where $x \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^\infty; \mathbb{Z})$. We also know that $x^2 \in H^4(\mathbb{CP}^\infty; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is a generator and $x^3$ generates $H^6(\mathbb{CP}^\infty;\mathbb{Z})$ and so on. It seems like $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ would behave just like $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty;\mathbb{Z})$ multiplicatively after degree $2$ but the problem is that $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and if I take a generator $y \in H^4(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$, its cup product $y^2 = y \cup y$ lies in $H^8(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ and multiplicatively we "miss" $H^6(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ so to speak.

It seems like $y$ in $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty/\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathbb{Z})$ should be something resembling $x^2$ in $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty;\mathbb{Z})$, but I don't see any way to make this precise or even if it's the correct way to approach the problem.

Comment: What about $x^2$ and $x^3$?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "finitely many generators" hints at the fact that one generator, as with $H^*(\mathbb C P^\infty)$, will not be enough. You have witnessed that $y$ does not alone work as a generator. Yet it has to be included as a generator. What if you also include the thing that it "misses"? Notice that you will have relations as the result.

Also, $H^0(X)$ is functions on path components of $X$. $\mathbb C P^\infty$ was evidently path-connected, and taking quotient can't break path-connectedness. How many $0$-cells are there in $\mathbb{CP}^\infty -\mathbb{CP}^1$?

Comment: Yes you are correct, there should only be one $0$-cell in $\mathbb{CP}^\infty - \mathbb{CP}^1$, for some reason I made a mistake in writing down the cells in dimension $0$. Thanks!

Comment: @Perturbative Wait, there are no $0$-cells in $\mathbb{CP}^\infty - \mathbb{CP}^1$: you discard the only one from $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$. But there will be one in the quotient space - the one into which you contract $\mathbb{CP}^1$.